# Сравнить число с каждым элементом списка

Tags: python, list, сравнение

Есть список со списками внутри

```py
complaint_stat = [
                  [27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15],
                  [12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121],
                  [5, 7, 6, 13, 2, 1, 25],
                  [15, 6, 14, 19, 25, 7, 3]
]
```

И еще список

```py
week_avg = [26, 52, 14, 22]
```

Надо сравнить сравнить с каждым элементом списка

**26** с каждым из 27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15

**52** с каждым из 12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121

и так далее.

Подскажите алгоритм...

Comment: сравнить с каждым элементом списка

Comment: `for x,y in zip(complaint_stat, week_avg): for z in x:  # сравниваем z и y`

Comment: Вы какой результат хотите получить? набор булевых значений? использование модуля numpy вас устроит?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
import numpy as np

complaint_stat = [
                  [27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15],
                  [12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121],
                  [5, 7, 6, 13, 2, 1, 25],
                  [15, 6, 14, 19, 25, 7, 3]
]

week_avg = [26, 52, 14, 22]

a = np.array(complaint_stat)
for i in week_avg:
    print(np.signbit(a-i))
```

в итоге вы получите четыре массива (по количеству элементов в week_avg, в булевыми значениями, в данном примере, если число из списка week_avg больше complaint_stat, то True, иначе - False:

```
[[False  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]]
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]]
[[False False False  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False False  True  True]]
[[False False  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True False  True  True]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy. Сравнение в одну операцию. Я угадал?

```
import numpy as np


complaint_stat = np.array([
    [27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15],
    [12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121],
    [5, 7, 6, 13, 2, 1, 25],
    [15, 6, 14, 19, 25, 7, 3]
])

week_avg = np.array([26, 52, 14, 22])

print(complaint_stat >= week_avg[:, np.newaxis])
```

> ```
> $ python compare.py
> [[ True False False False False False False]
>  [False False False False False False  True]
>  [False False False False False False  True]
>  [False False False False  True False False]]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Всю проверку можно уложить в одну строчку. Вот так она будет выглядеть для условия "больше".

```
complaint_stat = [
              [27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15],
              [12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121],
              [5, 7, 6, 13, 2, 1, 25],
              [15, 6, 14, 19, 25, 7, 3]
            ]
week_avg = [26, 52, 14, 22]

result = [list(map(w.__gt__, c)) for w,c in zip(week_avg, complaint_stat)]
print(result)
```

Результат:

```
[[False, True, True, True, True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, False],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, False],
 [True, True, True, True, False, True, True]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Вариант реализации стандартными средствами языка без изысков, для начинающих ;)

complaint_stat = [
    [27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15],
    [12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121],
    [5, 7, 6, 13, 2, 1, 25],
    [15, 6, 14, 19, 25, 7, 3]
]
week_avg = [26, 52, 14, 22]

# enumerate(seq) возвращает последовательность кортежей из индекса и значения,
# которые распаковываются в переменные i и avg соответственно
for i, avg in enumerate(week_avg):
    try:
        for num in complaint_stat[i]:
            # подставляете любое требуемое сравнение
            # можете также сохранить результат в список
            print(num > avg, end=" ")
    except IndexError:
        # ваша обработка
        break
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
complaint_stat = [
              [27, 22, 15, 8, 3, 16, 15],
              [12, 4, 10, 13, 29, 22, 121],
              [5, 7, 6, 13, 2, 1, 25],
              [15, 6, 14, 19, 25, 7, 3]
            ]
week_avg = [27, 52, 14, 22]
for i in range(len(complaint_stat)):
    if week_avg[i] in complaint_stat[i]:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Если я правильно понял, что надо проверить есть ли первый элемент списка week_avg в первом вложенном списке списка complaint_stat, и т.д.

Comment: нет, проверить что 26 больше чем 27 затем больше ли 22 и т.д

Comment: @KAmeradKAmerad тогда вместо ифов напишите цикл перебора вложенных списков.

Comment: Да понятно что цикл в цикле, вопрос что брать, попросил пример